# How to add groovy in intellij?

Tags: java, groovy, plugins, frameworks

How to configure the groovy in Intellij and I have to download the groovy pluigins? 
How to run the groovy test case in intellij?
Can any one guide me properly to my Questions.

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/getting-started-with-groovy.html

Answer (score 0):

The sequence is trivial:

Right click on your project -> Add Framework support... -> Choose groovy and specify the GDK path